# Word for something that "helps solve a problem"

Tags: single-word-requests

This is the sentence I'm writing

> The system requires a stiff solver and appropriate ______, such as the Jacobian Matrix Pattern

I've been thinking of *workarounds*, but the example given is not something that avoids the problem or finds an alternate solution, but it helps in solving the original problem, making it much faster. They are not needed, but they help a great deal. Also *Pattern* is not the only one of these.

*devices* does not sound right either, because it evokes a physical object.

Maybe *aids*, but it is more related to people or humanitarian causes.

**Is there a single word to express a group of (non-physical) things that help you reach a solution?**

Comment: *Method? Approach? Model*? What *is* a "Jacobian Matrix Pattern"? And why not just call it a, well, *pattern*? You listed a few words that don't work, but forgot to specify what it is that you are after. It's hard to tell you how to best express something without knowing what it is you are trying to express.

Comment: _tools_ is another possibility. This is often used metaphorically to refer to methods rather than physical tools.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I tried to clarify the question. Is it better?
Thank you for your suggestions, but I have used them before in other contexts and I do not want to confuse people.

Comment: @Barmar - +1 for 'tool'. Couldn't be better. A tool is something that helps you get the job done but doesn't do it all by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *tool* is often used metaphorically to refer to methods and software. For instance, a word processor is a common tool of writers and editors. And the Socratic Method is a tool employed by teachers.

See these definitions in [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tool):

> 1.1 A thing used in an occupation or pursuit:
>   *computers are an essential tool*
>   *the ability to write clearly is a tool of the trade*
>
> 1.3 Computing: A piece of software that carries out a particular function, typically creating or modifying another program.

Comment: I'm going to add "numerical" so it is clear what I am talking about, but *tool* is definitely the best option. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Although you have discounted it, I do think that ***device*** would work well here, perhaps with a qualifying, attributive adjective.

Likewise, I think that, whilst *tool* is used more commonly used in such circumstances, ***aid*** is also appropriate and would convey your meaning clearly.

> *The system requires a stiff solver and appropriate **algorithmic device**, such as the Jacobian Matrix Pattern.*
>
> *A **numerical device** such as the Jacobian Matrix Pattern greatly assists in solving the problem.*
>
> *An appropriate **algorithmic device**, such as the Jacobian Matrix Pattern, is an invaluable **aid** for computing the solution.*

Comment: I think *tool* is the best and easiest answer. I will add "numerical" from your suggestions to specify the type of tools. +1!

Answer (score 1):

Might you consider using an adverb more specific to the function you are trying to describe? Perhaps "appropriate" is slightly too non-specific. However, if that is the word which suits your fancy, I might consider "application" to fill in your blank for these three reasons:

1. A little alliteration never hurts to smooth over awkward meanings in sentences because the reader's creativity gets engaged. Literary devices are a "stuck" writer's best friend.
2. The term "application" implies a quality of particularity, although it also leaves room for a broader sense of usage.
3. "Application" also seems to fit your conditional clause here:

> "...it helps in solving the original problem, making it much faster. They
>   are not needed, but they help a great deal."

Best of luck! I look forward to reading your outcome. =)

Comment: What I did was activate or deactivate some of the options in the solver, toggled parameters, provided variables and matrices that sped up the solution.  I have the feeling *application* is something more complex than the... *tools* I implemented. +1 though!

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you so much for the update and plus one! I'm glad you got your word. =)

Answer (score 0):

How about "**process**"? (from Webster: *a series of actions that lead to a particular result*)

Answer (score 0):

> The system requires a stiff solver and appropriate **models**, such
>   as the Jacobian Matrix Pattern.
>
> - (n), a hypothetical description of a complex entity or process

- “the computer program was based on a model of the circulatory and
  respiratory systems”.([vocab.com/suggested in comments, too](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/model?family=models))

Comment: I can't use *model* because the system is the solution of a model; I do not want to repeat myself and do not want to confuse the reader. Thank you though!